# Does drinking milk make people produce more phlegm?

Tags: milk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do dairy products cause phlegm to build or thicken?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7854/do-dairy-products-cause-phlegm-to-build-or-thicken)

It's commonly told that one shouldn't drink milk before singing because it causes him to produce more mucus and therefore phlegm and disrupt his singing. I've heard conflicting things about whether this is true or not though. Is it?

Comment: @Oddthinking: yep